# is it possible to define a variable field name in an array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

i need to push values in an array, but this array is always with different number of elements, and some of them are numbered i would like to have something like:

```
{"idWeb":223,"category":"animals","questionText":"have you got animals?","howManyAnswers":2,"answerText1":"yes","risid1":43,"answerText2":"no","risid2":44}
```

for this array, for example the variable names should be answertext1 and answertext2.

so at a time, i will have something like this:

```
$arrayname['answertext'.$a] = "some sentence string";
```

is it right?

Comment: have you tried doing it?

Comment: Yes: http://ideone.com/45LTqR

Comment: i hope you are creating it as $arrayname=array(/* all stuff you want */)
It should work.

Comment: Yes why not! Try it and see

Answer (score 0):

Yes its correct..
For example

```
$arr = array( 'a1'=>12,'a2'=>32,'a3'=>22,'a3'=>33 );
$x=1;
print_r($arr['a'.$x]);
```

This will output 12.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there's no problem using vars as key names in associative arrays in PHP, for example:

```
$a = 1;
$b = 2;

$arrayname['answertext'.$a] = "some sentence string A";
$arrayname['answertext'.$b] = "some sentence string B";

echo $arrayname['answertext'.$a] . "<br/>"; //"some sentence string A"
echo $arrayname['answertext1'] . "<br/>"; //"some sentence string A"

echo $arrayname['answertext'.$b] . "<br/>"; //"some sentence string B"
echo $arrayname['answertext2'] . "<br/>"; //"some sentence string B"
```

To create an associative array with array( ), use the => symbol to separate indexes from values:

```
$array = array(
    "foo" => "bar",
    "bar" => "foo",
);

// a partir de PHP 5.4
$array = [
    "foo" => "bar",
    "bar" => "foo",
];
```

To construct an empty array, pass no arguments to array( ):

```
$addresses = array(  );
```

More info about arrays:
http://oreilly.com/catalog/progphp/chapter/ch05.html